# Check a type trait of every class in a nested mixin

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a collection of mixins that each have a type trait defined. I want to check the value of the boolean AND of each of this trait for each of these mixins. For example, if I have a `Mixin1<Mixin2<T> >` and `Mixin1<T>` has `is_nice == true` while `Mixin2<T>` has `is_nice == false`, then the trait of the nested mixins should evaluate to "false".

```
#include <iostream>

// A type trait to determine if a type is nice
template <typename T>
struct is_nice
{
  static const bool value = false;
};

// Base case
template <class T>
struct is_nice_all {
    static_assert(is_nice<typename T::FieldsType>::value, "Not nice!");

    static const bool value = is_nice<typename T::FieldsType>::value;
};

template <template <class> class Outer, class Inner>
struct is_nice_all<Outer<Inner> > {
    // AND the result of the niceness of the current mixin and the next mixin, recursively
    static const bool value = is_nice< typename Outer<Inner>::FieldsType >::value && is_nice_all<Inner>::value;
};

class BaseClass
{
public:
    using FieldsType = BaseClass;
};

template <>
struct is_nice<BaseClass>
{
  static const bool value = true;
};

class Mixin1_Fields
{
public:
    int property1;
};

template<class MixinBase>
class Mixin1 : public MixinBase, public Mixin1_Fields
{
public:
    using FieldsType = Mixin1_Fields;
};

template <>
struct is_nice<Mixin1_Fields>
{
  static const bool value = true;
};

class Mixin2_Fields
{
public:
    int property2;
};

template<class MixinBase>
class Mixin2 : public MixinBase, public Mixin2_Fields
{
public:

    using FieldsType = Mixin2_Fields;
};

template <>
struct is_nice<Mixin2_Fields>
{
  static const bool value = true;
};

class Mixin3_Fields
{
public:
    int property3;
};

template<class MixinBase>
class Mixin3 : public MixinBase, public Mixin3_Fields
{
public:
    using FieldsType = Mixin3_Fields;
};

template <>
struct is_nice<Mixin3_Fields>
{
  static const bool value = false;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << is_nice_all<Mixin1<Mixin2<BaseClass> > >::value << std::endl;

    std::cout << is_nice_all<Mixin1<Mixin3<BaseClass> > >::value << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Is this "weird" or a reasonable thing to do? I don't see a ton about using mixins like this online - is this pattern for adding attributes not often used in practice?

Comment: Perhaps you want `static const bool value = is_nice< Outer<Inner> >::value && is_nice_all<Inner>::value;`. Note that in your example this would output 0 though, as you haven't defined the template specializations for `Mixin1` and `Mixin2`. I'm not sure how you would check `is_nice` a particular base class of `Outer`, i.e. the `Mixin1_Fields` and `Mixin2_Fields` that you have template specializations for.

Comment: @user2093113 Wow, I was so focused on the hard part that I botched the obvious part. I've updated the question with the working example. But I'm still curious if this is "weird" or a reasonable thing to do.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to just inherit from a `nicer_tag` and just check inheritance from it ?

Comment: @Jarod42 If any of the mixins derived from `nicer_tag` then it would say the whole type was 'nice'. I want to require ALL of the mixins to be 'nice'. Or do you mean keep the recursion but just use `std::is_base_of` instead of the type trait?

Comment: I mean keeping the the recursion for `is_nice_all`, and use `std::is_base_of` instead of the traits. That seems simplify all your classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to do the recursion on itself, but just on `Inner`, and use regular value for current type

```
template <template <class> class Outer, class Inner>
struct is_nice_all<Outer<Inner> > {
    // AND the result of the niceness of the current mixin and the next mixin, recursively
    static const bool value = is_nice<typename Outer<Inner>::FieldsType>::value
                              && is_nice_all<Inner>::value;
};
```

Comment: What do you mean that the trait doesn't apply to Derived? Is there a different way to define the trait so it would apply?

Comment: I didn't follow the `FieldsType` tricks to propagate traits. So your code works.